# Can I show private youtube videos on exoplayer without showing url to the user in android app

Tags: android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

In my project I want to show the Youtube private videos to the user who logged in in my app.Here I just planned that I am calling an api and get the url from the backend.I am going to use `Exoplayer` for showing videos.Here I want to know can I show private video on exoplayer without exposing url to the user?
If not suggest me any other way to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by exposing the url ?

Comment: url should not visible to user

Comment: I'm not sure to understand, you only have to show the title of your video in your UI and give the url to your `SimpleExoPlayer` then the url won't be visible to the user

Comment: Okay let me try it.Is it possible to show private (Restricted) videos on simpleExoPlayer

Comment: I don't know I haven't actually tried playing such video but as long as you have the URL it should be fine, you just need to make your video "unlisted" or something like that

Comment: Okay.I will try this and will update you.Thanks